# How to create a binary matrix with rand() and a specific proportion of ones?

Tags: matrix, julia

I am setting up my mathematical model, but now I am struggling with
manipulating the data.

I want to create a random binary matrix (0,1) where the ratio of 1 over the total is equal to some specific value like 0.3. How can I do that with `rand()` function?

In excel you would do it like the following for the probability of returning 1 is 0.2:

```
= IF(RAND() < 0.2, 1, 0)
```

Answer (score 7):

## With a comprehension list

This should do the trick, I here suppose that you want a 3x8 Matrix:

```
function create_random_matrix(n::Int, m::Int)
           [rand() < 0.2 for _ in 1:n, _ in 1:m]
end

mymatrix = create_random_matrix(3,8)
```

## ifelse and ternary operator for a more complicated matrix

You might need [`ifelse` function](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Core.ifelse) if you want something more complicated, a matrix of something else than binaries for instance:

```
function create_random_matrix(n::Int, m::Int)
      [ifelse(rand() < 0.2, 10.0, -5.0+rand()) for _ in 1:n, _ in 1:m]
end
```

Or a similar way using [ternary operator](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/control-flow/index.html):

```
function create_random_matrix(n::Int, m::Int)
      [rand() < 0.2 ? 10.0 : -5.0+rand() for _ in 1:n, _ in 1:m]
end
```

## Array of Arrays instead of 2-dimensional Array

I here supposed you want a `2-dimensional Array` to represent your matrix. You might want an `Array of Arrays` instead:

```
function create_random_matrix(n::Int, m::Int, prob::Float64)
      [[rand() < prob for _ in 1:n] for _ in 1:m]
end
```

## Without putting it in a function

Without putting it in a function:

```
mymatrix = [[rand() < 0.3 for _ in 1:3] for _ in 1:8]
```

## With a distribution law

You also can, using [`Distributions` package](https://juliastats.github.io/Distributions.jl/stable/starting/), do the following:

```
#Using Pkg; Pkg.add("Distributions") #Uncomment if you didn't already install Distributions package
using Distributions
mymatrix = rand(Bernoulli(0.3), 3, 8)
```

## With a bitwise operator

Finally you can also use:

```
mymatrix = rand(3, 8) .< 0.3
```

Which is a simple solution notationally and returns a [`BitArray`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/arrays/index.html#Base.BitArray) which may or may not be what you need. This also has the inconvenient to create an unnecessarily array.

### Improved thanks to

This answer has been improved thanks to the comments of @Bogumił Kamiński and @DNF.

Comment: alternatively you can write `using Distributions` and then e.g. `rand(Bernoulli(0.1), 10, 10)`.

Comment: `Distributions` should be the preferred way here. Easier for people looking for similar solutions.

Comment: It's a bit strange to write `rand() < 0.3 ? true : false`, since this is exactly equivalent to `rand() < 0.3`. You're basically writing "if A is true, then true, else false", instead of just "A". So replace all your examples with `[rand() < 0.3 for ...]` and similar.

Comment: A very simple solution notationally is `mymatrix = rand(m, n) .< 0.3`. It creates an extra array unnecessarily, but it's very straightforward. It also returns a `BitArray` which may or may not be what you want.

Comment: @DNF, thank you for your comment, I edited my answer according to what you suggest :)